# CSS - scroll content not expanding properly

Tags: html, css, height, scrollbar, overflow

The problem is like this (https://jsfiddle.net/Lpm2ghsr/4/)

As you scroll, you can see by the background color that the height of **.content** is somehow the same as that of the container, instead of expanding to the height of the actual content.

Adding "height: 100%" to the content doesn't seem to work as 100% meaning the same height as its parent I suppose?

I've tried adding "overflow: auto" to .content but it's not really what I want since the scrollbar should be outside as shown in the example.

Here is the HTML markup

```
<header></header>
<div class="container">
  <section class="content">
    <pre>some text
    some text
    some text
    some text
    some text
    some text</pre>
  </section>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 99%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
header{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  position: relative;
}
.content{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

pre{
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: why do you have `height: calc(100% - 100px)` in .container? If you set that to just 100% it should work. Another issue I noticed is your section/div closing tags are the wrong way around.

Comment: This? https://jsfiddle.net/Lpm2ghsr/3/

Comment: @Dana Thanks, I've corrected the tags. Since the header is 100px hegiht, .container should exclude that 100px, shoudn't it? Setting it to 100% will make the scrollbar too long that it'd disappear at the bottom.

Comment: @Michael_B That looks right! Is there any other approach with minimal changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is the simplest way. Try this.

Your main content is in "contents" class, so apply height to contents class.
Try the below modified code.

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.content{
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  background-color: #bbb;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: This is just what I want! Thanks! One question though, does overflow:auto; have to be applied to .container?

Comment: Not needed, since we have set the height of the container to 100%, overflow will be required only for the inner contents.

Answer (score 1):

Change .container display to block from flex and it will work.

```
.container {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to keep display: flex for the layout of its child elements. The content was actually more complicated than it is in the example. Sorry for not making that clear in the question.